# FaceBook Login Integration Key hashes error?

Tags: ionic4

> Trying to connect facebook login in ionic 4 application but it shows
>   keyhashes error happend?

Answer (score 0):

> > change the config.xml file APP ID and APP NAME

**Platform Android**

```
<platform name="android">
   <config-file parent="/resources" target="./res/values/strings.xml">
      <string name="fb_app_id">xxxxxxxxxx</string>
      <string name="fb_app_name">xxxxxxx</string>
   </config-file>
</platform>
```

**Platform iOS**

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^3.1.0">
      <variable name="APP_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
       <variable name="APP_NAME" value="xxxxxxx" /> 
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're getting an error on login with Android and it shows a key hash? You need to add all key hashes that you see in those error messages to the setting of your Facebook app. Go to developers.facebook.com/yourappid, to settings > basic, scroll down to key hashes and add it there.

It seems that the different facebook applications on the users phone can change the hash that needs to be allowed for them. We've got 4 different hashes for ours now and I'm sure they'll be more going forward. I'd recommend setting up a logger for client errors so you can get those hashes as they pop up.